# Returning data to nested field from computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a blog article creation field, in which each field is gathered into `fields: {}` object.

```
data: {
  fields: {
    title: '',
    slug: ''
  }
},
```

I want to take the title and use a `slugify` method on that value, from which the computed should return the end-slug into the slug input.

This would work on a non-nested field:

```
computed: {
  slug: function () {
    return this.slugify(this.fields.title)
  }
},
```

How can I access the nested field from `computed`?

**Inputs:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
                   v-model="fields.title" placeholder="Enter your title">

<input v-model="fields.slug" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
```

I need to use `v-model` on both inputs.

This works well and i get the slug, the problem is is that the data in `fields.slug` is not changing. How do I get my computed slug value into my `fields.slug`?

Comment: where's the input property and the slugify method?

Comment: i added the inputs, but i dont think the slugify method is relevant

Comment: If slugify is not relevent then return it as such in the computed property I mean...////// return this.fields.slug;//////

Comment: hecc, i mean its relevant, it slugifyies and replaces inside a string, i just dont think its relevant to put into the post to pollute, I just need to get the response to fields.data inside the computed